# Calculating at binary level in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary

In my 2D environment a player can move diagonally, horizontally and vertically. When looking at the grid below you can see that the player (marked as `x`) can move to 8 different spots from where he (or she xD) is now.

```
 1 | 2 | 3
-----------
 4 | x | 5
-----------
 6 | 7 | 8
```

Instead of storing this as (which is a lot of data):

```
Go1 = true;
Go2 = true;
Go3 = true;
Go4 = true;
Go5 = true;
Go6 = true;
Go7 = true;
Go8 = true;
```

I think it's better to first convert it to:

```
11111111
```

..which represents 8 times true. With that in mind and the knowledge that the decimal representation of the binary number `11111111` (8 bit) equals the nummer: `255` I rather convert it and store the current-possible-places-to-move-to as `255`.

Code:

```
x = parseInt(11111111);
var bin = x.toInt(2);
document.write(bin);​
```

That means that if there's a wall at (for example) location (1, 4 and 6) = left side from player, the player can only move to:

```
01101011
```

Which can be stored as: `107`.

Let's say that the player wants to move to location `3`. This means that my script has to do the following:

1. convert the 3 digit current-possible-places-to-move-to number back to binary
2. get the 3rd number from that binary code
3. check if that number is a 1 or 0

**Question:**
Is it possible to calculate this without converting to binary back and forth in Javascript? If yes, how?

Comment: Here's a good example from [Mozilla's js documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Example:_Flags_and_bitmasks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit-shift so that the relevant digit is the least significant, and then test the parity of the value:

```
function getPositionInRow(rowval, pos) {
    return (rowval >> (8 - pos)) % 2;
}
```

This will return value at the specified position, counting from the left starting the index at 1.

Comment: I think I had an off-by-one error; try my edit with `8` instead of `7`.  If you need to change the size of your row, just change that number to the row width (or you could just make it a third argument to the function.)

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong because `x = 255 >> (8 - 1) % 2;document.write(x);` prints `127`
​

Comment: JS order of operations means that the bit shift gets evaluated last here, after the modulo, so you're actually doing `255 >> ((8 - 1) % 2)` = `255 >> 1`.  You want to do the modulo last: `x = (255 >> (8 - 1)) % 2`